# do i have to create login for database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating Database in SQL Server using T-SQL(using C# to run script).
I am confused:

If I create the Database logged in as user: "myUser1" (myUser1 is a login I created, with db_creator role).

Do I have to create a login for this user in T-SQL like:

```
CREATE LOGIN [myUser1] WiTH Password = "test"
Go
Exec sp_grantdbaccess, myUser1
Go
```

Or I don't need this?

Comment: A `login` is needed to access the server as a whole; for each database, you need to create a **`user`** for that specific database, based on the `login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [new login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)

```
CREATE LOGIN LoginName
    WITH PASSWORD = 'password';
```

Add a [new user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) to this login:

```
USE NameOfDataBase;


GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   sys.database_principals
               WHERE  name = N'LoginName')
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER [LoginName] FOR LOGIN [LoginName];
        EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'LoginName';
    END
```

Comment: difference between LoginName and NewUserName?

Comment: Updated above script.  I went through this week before last, but can't find my script.

Comment: LoginName and UserName can be same?

Answer (score 1):

After creating the login you need to create a user for that login on every database you wish to use.

```
 use [Database]
 Create USER [user] FOR LOGIN [user]

 exec sp_addrolemember N'role',N'user'
```

Comment: Do i not have to add Password?